# WSS V2 to v3 pages migrated as 0 size

Tags: migration

Currently doing a migration project from v2 to v3 of WSS. Most of the sites migrate really well, however one site which has a lot of pages are behaving strangly when migrated.
As it is wss they are simply aspx pages sitting in a library with markup and occassionally a webpart in them.
When the site is migrated all the pages are there but most of them are 0 bytes size and do not load at all. 
Has anyone seen this before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have resolved this , the file path for the webpart page template was customised in v2. Adding a file mapping in the upgrade file to redirect to the sts webpart page template did the trick.